# Tcl 8.6 installation issue on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, 64-bit, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to build 64 bit of Tcl/Tk on Mac OS X Lion.

1. Downloading the source from [source forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/?source=directory)
2. `./configure --enable-framework --enable-64-bit --prefix=/usr/local`
3. `make`
4. `sudo make install`

Everything works fine up to make, but with `make install`, I have version conflict error.

```
Installing private header files to     
/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.6/PrivateHeaders/
ERROR: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.9, need 8.6
If running this script from 'make html', set the NATIVE_TCLSH environment
variable to point to an installed tclsh8.6 (or the equivalent tclsh86.exe
on Windows).
make: *** [html-tcl] Error 1
```

What went wrong? How to fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I needed to pass NATIVE_TCLSH directly to make rather than through the environment:

```
sudo make install NATIVE_TCLSH=/usr/local/bin/tclsh8.6
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to set environment variable: `TCL_VERSION=8.6 sudo make install`.

Comment: This did not work for me. I did export TCL_VERSION=8.6; sudo make install and got the same error.

Comment: This didn't work for me either (same error as described in OP) even though I *did* remember to use sudo's -E option to pass environment variables ;)

Answer (score 0):

This line worked for me:

```
sudo make install NATIVE_TCLSH=/usr/local/bin/tclsh8.6
```

I thought I have to put `NATIVE_TCLSH=/usr/local/bin/tclsh8.6` in front of the `sudo make install` command..